# Stop word in elasticsearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch, solr, lucene, opensearch

In Elasticsearch, when searching with a stop keyword like "is," "on," or "the," it gets replaced with "?" during the search process. For instance, "circular on AI" becomes "circular ? AI," yielding the expected result. However, undesired results such as "circular of AI" or "circular demo AI" also appear. While it's acceptable for "?" to be replaced by a stop word, it's problematic when replaced by any word. The desired outcome is to obtain results containing only stop words, like "circular stop word AI." How can I achieve this specific behavior in Elasticsearch?

When using Elasticsearch, a search with stop keywords like "is" gets replaced with "?" but may also yield results with arbitrary words like "of" or "demo." To ensure results only include stop words, such as "circular stop word AI," rather than any word, how can this be achieved in Elasticsearch?

Comment: This is the same question as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77536560/issues-on-searching-with-stop-words. Maybe delete the other one if this one is of better quality.

Comment: I'm not sure how this is related to Solr?